# Java weird rectangle rendering

Tags: java, graphics, rendering

I would like to ask if it is a bug or not.

When I use fillRect method then it renders a rectangle about a pixel smaller than method drawRect.

Does anyone else have same problem as me? :(
Or does exist a fix for this problem?

Here is a tiny sample code bellow:

```
public Frame(){
    super("Sample rectangle");
    setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setUndecorated(true);       
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    //g.drawRect(0,0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
    //wrap.graphics(g);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is exactly as described in the relevant [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> **fillRect**
> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1
>
> **drawRect**
> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height.

Comment: Lol that sucks. Why the heck I would want draw a rectangle about width -1 and height -1. It is not even meant for a border because for border it should be width -2 and height -2 with X +1 and Y +1.

Comment: Is there a way to draw correct width and height of filled rectangle? I mean without writing +1 like an i*iot

Comment: Add one to your width and height parameters.

Comment: If you mean: a fill of exactly the same area as the draw, then of course: just add 1 to the width and the height while calling fillRect!

Comment: Just up to dated my comment. Sorry :(

Comment: "Why the heck I would want draw a rectangle about width -1 and height -1" A rectangle between `x` and `x + width - 1` is `width` pixels wide, similarly for the height.

Comment: Just noticed drawRect is the problem one. It is about +1 pixel wider

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (emphasis mine):

`drawRect`

> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and **x + width**. The top and bottom edges are at y and **y + height**. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics context's current color.

`fillRect`

> Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and **x + width - 1**. The top and bottom edges are at y and **y + height - 1**. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.

Comment: Is there a way to draw correct width and height of filled rectangle?

Comment: The current way of drawing is _correct_. It works as specified. I believe it was designed this way so that you can easily draw a table, where two adjacent cells will have a single-pixel outline (overlapping outlines).

Comment: If I wanted to draw a table then I would draw it `fillRect(x,y,width,height)` and then `drawRect(x-1,y-1,width+2,height+2)` :S. I think I will better move to C and Allegro. Java just start to kinda pissing me off :(

Comment: yeah, you can do that too :)

Comment: how? **drawRect** draws it **x+width** and **fillRect** **x+width-1** there is one just one pixel difference :(

Comment: That is a trade-off you are going to have to make as the API is designed this way. It most probably fits at least as many people as it annoys.